# So I just created a text file and copied text from an already existing file using a with loop. How do I open newly created file in same prog?

Tags: python, string, file, replace, count

I'm making a program that takes text from an input file, then you input a file where it copies the already existing file text. Then, I need to replace a few words there and print the count of how many of these words were replaced. This is my code so far, but since `with` loops close the newly created file, I have no idea how to open it back again for reading and writing and counting. This is my awful code so far:

```
filename=input("Sisesta tekstifaili nimi: ")
inputFile=open(filename, "r")
b=input("Sisesta uue tekstifaili nimi: ")
uusFail=open(b+".txt", "w+")
f=uusFail
with inputFile as input:
    with uusFail as output:
        for line in input:
            output.write(line)

lines[]
asendus = {'hello':'tere', 'Hello':'Tere'}
with uusFail as infile
    for line in infile
        for src, target in asendus
            line = line, replace(src, target)
        lines.append(line)
    with uusFail as outfile:
        for line in lines:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You really don't want to use `input` as a variable name. If you want something simple, I tend to use `file_in`.

Comment: Why don't you just do the counting and replacing during the `for line in input:` loop?

Comment: [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statements aren't "loops" per se. They may wrap one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of unnecessary loops in your code. when you read the file, you can treat it as a whole and count the number of occurrences and replace them. Here is a modified version of your code:

```python
infile = input('Enter file name: ')
outfile = input('enter out file: ')
with open(infile) as f:
  content = f.read()
asendus = {'hello':'tere', 'Hello':'Tere'}
my_count = 0
for src, target in asendus.items():
  my_count += content.count(src)
  content = content.replace(src, target)


with open(f'{outfile}.txt','w+' ) as f:
  f.write(content)
```

Comment: why did you add another outfile in the end? i want the replacement to take place in the first outfile you create. you created another extra file

Comment: @RCWZX you just need to remove the `2` in that case. But why are you writing to the file if you want to overwrite directly?

Comment: i would just like it to do the replacements from the infile and then copy it to one outfile.

Comment: @RCWZX in that case you only need the second with statement. I have updated the code with the changes. In any case, what you needed to do was to work on the content directly and then only save it when you need to.

Comment: thank you so much, i'll analyze the code to make sure i'll understand everything ;)

Comment: @RCWZX thanks. If you feel that this answer helped you, could you mark it with the green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reopen the file in the second block of code:

```
with open(b+".txt", "r") as infile:
```